# According to Preterism has Matthew 19:27-30 been fulfilled? If so, when?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, eschatology, preterism

> Mat 19:27  Then answered Peter and said unto him, Behold, we have
>   forsaken all, and followed thee; what shall we have therefore?  Mat
>   19:28  And Jesus said unto them, Verily I say unto you, That ye which
>   have followed me, in the regeneration when the Son of man shall sit in
>   the throne of his glory, ye also shall sit upon twelve thrones,
>   judging the twelve tribes of Israel.  Mat 19:29  And every one that
>   hath forsaken houses, or brethren, or sisters, or father, or mother,
>   or wife, or children, or lands, for my name's sake, shall receive an
>   hundredfold, and shall inherit everlasting life.  Mat 19:30  But many
>   that are first shall be last; and the last shall be first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't look at any full preterist sources, but partial preterists like the theologian John Gill take that this passage as fulfilled, so I suspect anyone who is preterist on this passage will agree to a large extent with following excerpts from [John Gill's Exposition](https://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/gills-exposition-of-the-bible/matthew-19-28.html):

v28. And Jesus said unto them, Verily I say unto you, That ye which have followed me, ...

**in the regeneration**

> not in the resurrection of the dead, or at the last judgment, but in this new state of things, which now began to appear with another face: for the apostles having a new commission to preach the Gospel to all the world

**when the Son of man shall sit in the throne of his glory,**

> or glorious throne; as he did when he ascended into heaven, and sat down at the right hand of God

**ye also shall sit upon twelve thrones: judging the twelve tribes of Israel;**

> doctrinally and practically; by charging them with the sin of crucifying Christ, condemning them for their unbelief, and rejection of him, denouncing the wrath of God, and the heaviest judgments that should fall upon them, as a nation, for their sin; and by turning from them to the Gentiles, under which judgment they continue to this day.

v29. And every one that hath forsaken houses, or brethren, or sisters, or father, or mother, or wife, or children, or lands, for my name's sake ...

**shall receive an hundredfold,**

> in this world; which may be understood either in spiritual things, the love of God, the presence of Christ, the comforts of the Holy Ghost, the communion of saints, and the joys and pleasures felt in the enjoyment of these things, being an hundred times more and better to them, than all they have left or lost for Christ's sake; or in temporal things, so in Mark it seems to be explained, that such shall now receive an hundred fold,

**and shall inherit everlasting life**

> The other evangelists add, "in the world to come", which is infinitely best of all; for this is an inheritance incorruptible, undefiled, which fades not away, reserved in the heavens, when all other inheritances are corruptible, defiled, fading and perishing; houses fall, relations die, friends fail, and lands and estates do not continue for ever: they then have the best of it, who being called, in providence, to quit all terrene enjoyments for Christ's sake, are favoured with his presence here, and shall enjoy eternal glory and happiness with him in another world.